# Haproxy open and listen tcp ports in a range

Tags: ubuntu, load-balancing, haproxy, high-availability

I want to listen to open and listen to a range of ports but this is very difficult it seems.

With the bind I can open to ports in that range. When I run a zenmap scan, it shows that the ports are open.

However listening for web01 is hard. I want to listen for the ports.

example: example.io:3007 I don't want it to direct to to web01 port 3011 but to 3007. 
However I thought removing 3011 and keeping it like

```
server web01 108.x1.xx3.xx9 check
```

did not work. I hope that anyone has a solution or a working example. That would be even better.

```
listen stratum-cluster
bind *:3000-4000
mode tcp
balance roundrobin
server web01 108.x1.xx3.xx9:3011 check
```

Removing the port :port from the server part doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your original attempt was correct. If you remove the port from the server line then it will use the same one as the incoming request. However you will need to add a `check port` because it wont know which port to do the health check on!:

```
server web01 108.x1.xx3.xx9 check port 3011
```

Check your status page to see if the health check is working.

Comment: Try something like:

server web01 108.x1.xx3.xx9 check port 3011

Documentation is here:
https://www.haproxy.com/doc/aloha/7.0/haproxy/healthchecks.html#checking-a-tcp-port

Comment: Sadly the removing of ports didn't work I found out.